# popup is not working after ajax response

Tags: jquery

I am using jquery popup , but it's not working after loading it from ajax

the **popup.js** is between

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
    $('a.poplight[href^=#]').click(function() {
     // code here
     }
    });
```

Do I have to use delegate? 
 Is it a problem because the document ready?

**NOTE :** 
I tried to remove the document ready and used this

```
    $(document).delegate("a.poplight[href^=#]",'click',function(e){
// code here
}
```

but it doesn't work

any help ?

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this

(jQuery >= 1.7)

```
$(document).on('click',"a.poplight[href^=#]",function(e){
// code here
});
```

OR

```
$('a.poplight[href^=#]').live(function() {
     // code here
});
```

OR

```
$('body').delegate('a.poplight[href^=#]', 'click', function() {
     // code here
});
```

Comment: @KJA which version of jQuery?